# htaccess URL fingerprinting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, caching, apache2.2

Is there a way to use `mod_rewrite` and htaccess to implement URL fingerprinting without having to change the file names with every update?

This is the file structure on the server (irrelevant files omitted):

```
/apps
    /foo
        /public
            /js
                file1.min.js
                file2.min.js
            /css
                file1.css
                file2.css
    /bar
        /public
            /js
                file1.min.js
                file2.min.js
            /css
                file1.css
                file2.css
```

My pages are in the application folders. The `<script>` elements in my pages look like this at the moment:

```html
<script src='public/js/file1.min.js'></script>
<script src='public/js/file2.min.js'></script>
```

I'd like to implement [URL fingerprinting](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching#invalidating-and-updating-cached-responses) so my elements would look like this:

```html
<script src='public/js/file1.1a516fba.min.js' integrity='sha384-...'></script>
<script src='public/js/file2.faf315f3.min.js' integrity='sha384-...'></script>
```

I could deploy every time with the file names changed but I am wondering if there is an easier way.

I tried this in my `.htaccess` file inside `apps`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^public/(css|js)/(.*)\.[0-9]+(\.css|\.js)$ /public/$1/$2.$3 [L, QSA]
</IfModule>
```

This did not work. I also tried variations of it and either ended up with HTTP 500 (completely failed) or 404 (rules did not work).

I'd like to avoid repeating a .htaccess in every application's folder if possible, and I'd like to keep the file in source control (so inside `/apps`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to capture `faf315f3` by only allowing digits - this is where the problem lies. You need to include alphas as well:

```bash
RewriteRule ^public/(css|js)/([^.]+).[0-9a-z]+((?:.min)?.(?:css|js))$ /public/$1/$2$3 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Additionally, I've made a few enhancements to your rule:

1. You need not escape periods in rules - these are only needed in conditions.
2. Use `[^.]+` (anything that is not a period) instead of `.*` (anything, zero-length and up) for the second capture-group.
3. Move the period outside of the last `css|js` capture as capturing would duplicate it in the destination URI.
4. Capture the entire group for the file extension, and make `.min` optional. This also means removing the period in the destination URI, resulting in `$1/$2$3`.

Comment: Thanks! I made some modifications to allow the hash to be optional, and also `.min` is not supposed to be optional.